# Error in R "unable to load shared object"

Tags: r

I have the following R error, which have been working before upgrading some of my dependencies.

> library(chromVAR)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘chromVAR’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/promises/libs/promises.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/promises/libs/promises.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE5rfindEcm
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/promises/libs/promises.so
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
> in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/promises/libs/promises.so

Similar things happen when calling another library

> library("GENOVA")
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GENOVA’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libgomp.1.dylib
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so
> Reason: image not found

From searching the websites(https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/13432), it seems these might be due to openssl upgrade.

My dependencies are as follows:

OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021)
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
MacOS Big Sur version 11.6

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Best,

Comment: You need to remove the affected packages (e.g. ‘promises’, ‘data.table’, probably others) and reinstall them from scratch, there’s a version mismatch with your compiler, and it’s also missing shared libraries (the OpenMP runtime). Also, your R version is *ancient*, I strongly recommend upgrading it since many packages won’t work with such an old version.

Comment: Hi Konrad, Thanks!! Re-installing R 4.1.1. completely worked fine!! Best,